# Why am I getting a foreign key mismatch when trying to insert unique values from parent table into child?

Tags: sql, sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

I am attempting to insert the unique values of the `Subject` field in `Main_Standards` into the `Name` field of `Subjects`, which is a foreign key referencing the `Subject` field.

Here is my `Main_Standards` table:

```
CREATE TABLE "Main_Standards" (
    "ID"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "Subfield"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Domain"    TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Code"  INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "Standard_Type" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Assessment_Type"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Subject"   TEXT,
    "Subject_Reference" TEXT,
    "Title" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Level" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Credits"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Grading_Scheme"    TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Status"    TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Expiry_Date"   TEXT,
    "Publication_Date"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "CurrentVersion"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Hyperlink" TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("ID" AUTOINCREMENT)
)
```

And here is my `Subjects` table.

```
CREATE TABLE "Subjects" (
    "ID"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "Name"  TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "Subfield"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Selected"  TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'False',
    FOREIGN KEY("Name") REFERENCES "Main_Standards"("Subject"),
    PRIMARY KEY("ID" AUTOINCREMENT)
)
```

This is the query resulting in the error thrown:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Subjects(Name, Subfield)
SELECT DISTINCT
Subject, 
Subfield
FROM Main_Standards
WHERE Standard_Type = 'A';
```

The error itself:

```
Execution finished with errors.
Result: foreign key mismatch - "Subjects" referencing "Main_Standards"
At line 1:
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Subjects(Name)
SELECT DISTINCT
Subject
FROM Main_Standards
WHERE Standard_Type = 'A';
```

Comment: Wouldn't Subject need to be declared unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html):

> Usually, the parent key of a foreign key constraint is the primary key of the parent table. If they are not the primary key, then the parent key columns must be collectively subject to a UNIQUE constraint or have a UNIQUE index.

`Main_Standards.Subject` is not the PK of the table, nor do you have anything to suggest there's a unique index on it. Thus, an error when you try to use it as a parent key.

---

Unrelated, but `PRIMARY KEY`s are, by definition, unique. You don't need to also specify `UNIQUE` with them. Doing so is a pessimization, as it creates a redundant index that has to be updated every time the table is modified.